# Which "controller" convert the XML response from a .NET WebService in JSON?

Tags: javascript, .net, xml, json, web-services

WebServices in .NET (asmx, but also wcf) use XML as schema for the information (due to the Saop protocol).

But on client side, after the web service method calling :

```
WebService.myOwnMethod("string", function (result) {
    console.log(result.Name);
});
```

I can manage result as Javascript object. So I think there is a conversion from XML to JSON? Or directly XML to Js object.

So, who made this parsification? The ScriptManager?

Comment: first of all, how do you call your web service and what kind of Web service are you calling (WCF can send json, asmx, can't)

Comment: I'm using asmx. I call web service on client trought the function above.

Comment: ok but how do get the WebService object ? which framework are you using on the client side ?

Comment: .NET 4.0. I get it trought the ScriptManager : `<asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Webservices/WebService.asmx" />`

Comment: @Blam : don't edit title please! I asked WHO convert, not How to :O

Comment: In English who refers to a person not a thing or process.

Comment: Yeah, sorry! I edited my answer, hope now is ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ResponseFormat to send data in JSON format like:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Description of your web method")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public returntype YourMethodName()
{
}
```

If your web service method has responseformat set to json, it will return data in json format.

Comment: You will need to add a using statment for reference of  System.Web.Script.Services;

Comment: I don't ask it! I ask which control translate XML to Js :)